# Serial write skips on Arduino Due

Tags: serial, arduino-due, serial-data

I bought Feetech SCS09 smart servos (also known as SCS009 or SCS0009).

**Please note that these servos are not regular PWM servos, they are devices that communicate with board using Serial connection via device named TTLinker that converts UART to half duplex protocol. So the question is about the problem with serial communication only.**

The seller provided me Arduino library to work with the servos.

The simplest testing sketch looks as this:

```
#include <SCServo.h>

SCServo SERVO;

void setup() {
  Serial2.begin(1000000);
  SERVO.pSerial = &Serial2;
  delay(500);
  SERVO.EnableTorque(1, 1);
  SERVO.EnableTorque(2, 1);
}

void loop() {
  SERVO.WritePos(1, 1023, 4000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x2FF
  SERVO.WritePos(2, 1023, 1000); // Servo ID:2, rotate to the position:0x2FF
  delay(4000);
  SERVO.WritePos(1, 20, 3000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x000
  SERVO.WritePos(2, 20, 1000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x000
  delay(3000);
}
```

**The code works perfectly on Arduino Mega** and allows to independently control servos.

But with Due I have problems: not all commands can be performed. So if compile the code for Due only servo ID1 works, but ID2 do not work at all.

When I add delays between commands the servos started to work

```
    SERVO.WritePos(1, 1023, 4000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x2FF
    delay(10);
    SERVO.WritePos(2, 1023, 1000); // Servo ID:2, rotate to the position:0x2FF
    delay(4000);
    SERVO.WritePos(1, 20, 3000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x000
    delay(10);
    SERVO.WritePos(2, 20, 1000); // Servo ID:1, rotate to the position:0x000
    delay(3000);
```

When I set delays between 1 and 9 the both servos can work but sometimes skip commands. Servos can skip 1-4 actions and then start to work again. The less delay I set the more random skips I get.

So I think here is some specialities regarding Serial connection on Arduino Due. What It can be? Why delays help to make it working?

By the way I read that Arduino Due can have problems with 1000000 baud rate and I tried different, even significntly less baud rates (for example 38400) with Arduino Due: the result is the same.

I need to explain how WritePos function works in the library

```
int SCSProtocol::WritePos(u8 ID, u16 Position, u16 Time, u16 Speed)
{
    return writePos(ID, Position, Time, Speed, INST_WRITE);
}

int SCSProtocol::writePos(u8 ID, u16 Position, u16 Time, u16 Speed, u8 Fun)
{
    flushSCS();
    u8 buf[6];
    Host2SCS(buf+0, buf+1, Position);
    Host2SCS(buf+2, buf+3, Time);
    Host2SCS(buf+4, buf+5, Speed);
    writeBuf(ID, P_GOAL_POSITION_L, buf, 6, Fun);
    return Ack(ID);
}

void SCSProtocol::Host2SCS(u8 *DataL, u8* DataH, int Data)
{
    if(End){
        *DataL = (Data>>8);
        *DataH = (Data&0xff);
    }else{
        *DataH = (Data>>8);
        *DataL = (Data&0xff);
    }
}

int SCSProtocol::Ack(u8 ID)
{
    if(ID != 0xfe && Level){
        u8 buf[6];
        u8 Size = readSCS(buf, 6);
        if(Size!=6){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void SCSProtocol::writeBuf(u8 ID, u8 MemAddr, u8 *nDat, u8 nLen, u8 Fun)
{
    u8 msgLen = 2;
    u8 bBuf[6];
    u8 CheckSum = 0;
    bBuf[0] = 0xff;
    bBuf[1] = 0xff;
    bBuf[2] = ID;
    bBuf[4] = Fun;
    if(nDat){
        msgLen += nLen + 1;
        bBuf[3] = msgLen;
        bBuf[5] = MemAddr;
        writeSCS(bBuf, 6);

    }else{
        bBuf[3] = msgLen;
        writeSCS(bBuf, 5);
    }
    CheckSum = ID + msgLen + Fun + MemAddr;
    u8 i = 0;
    if(nDat){
        for(i=0; i<nLen; i++){
            CheckSum += nDat[i];
        }
    }
    writeSCS(nDat, nLen);
    writeSCS(~CheckSum);
}

int SCServo::readSCS(unsigned char *nDat, int nLen)
{
    int Size = 0;
    int ComData;
    unsigned long t_begin = millis();
    unsigned long t_user;
    while(1){
        ComData = pSerial->read();
        if(ComData!=-1){
            if(nDat){
                nDat[Size] = ComData;
            }
            Size++;
            t_begin = millis();
        }
        if(Size>=nLen){
            break;
        }
        t_user = millis() - t_begin;
        if(t_user>IOTimeOut){
            break;
        }
    }
    return Size;
}

int SCServo::writeSCS(unsigned char *nDat, int nLen)
{
    if(nDat==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return pSerial->write(nDat, nLen);
}
```

So the problem is somewhere here: **Arduino Mega works good**, but it seems like Arduino Due have no time for on of the operations.

You can see more info here:

[Servo](http://ali.onl/Cd4)

[TTLinker device](http://ali.onl/Cd5)

[Arduino library](http://ragra.ru/SCServo.zip)

Comment: Please tell the name of the seller, give a link to your servo motors, give a link to the library that you use and to TTLinked. We would like to look into the hardware and library that you use, but then we have to know what you have.

Comment: I added links to my post, you can check, thanx

Comment: This is a tough problem. The TTLinker uses 5V signals, and the Due uses 3.3V signals, so you do need indeed a level converter. Can the level converter do 5V to 5V ? to try the Mega board via the level converter ? Do you use a fast logic level converter ? or a weak slow open drain level converter for I2C ? The way you describe the problem is most likely a software problem. The Arduino Due uses 32-bits integers, and the Mega 16-bits. However, I can't find a problem with 32 versus 16 in the library. With a logic analyzer you can get more information and get a little closer to the problem.

Comment: I have no experience of the Due, but I have just noticed that Tx0 has a higher max output current (15mA) than Tx1 (3mA), could that be having an affect?

Comment: Jot, I use this level converter http://ali.onl/CdL based on TXS0108E, I will try it with Mega to figure out whether it is the converter problem or not

Comment: I just connected the TTLinker directly without the level convereter. It work but with the same bug. So the level converter is not needed and it is definitely not a cause of the bug

Comment: @SergeyKravchenko I do not agree too much with your last sentence. I checked the Vih of the TTLinker and the Voh of the Due. The TTLinker I found states that the interface is a 74HC126D, powered at 5V. With these data, the Vih seems to be around 3.5V; your 3.3V powered due will never be able to reach this. Moreover the output voltage from the TTLinker is again 5V, and the Due is NOT 5V tolerant. So use the converter every time you attach it to the Due. Then, please show us the schematic you used (TXSs should have one side lower than the other, IIRC)

Comment: @fragugi87, I just tried it myself and saw the action in work by my own eyes:) to make it working I supplied TTLinker from Arduino Due 3.3V output, not 5V... moreover 74HC126D can work at 2-6V, it is written in the datasheet, so there is nothing strange... but the bug still exists: I can get proper working only with delays between commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that 250000 baud rate is the only choice for the Arduino Due with these servos. Less baud rates cause skips on Arduino Mega also, so this speed is not enough for fast data transfer.

Higher baud rates work good on Mega too but cause garbage on Due.

So let's summarize: these servos with TTLinker (TXS0108E) work good with Arduino Due at 250000 only and with Arduino Mega at 250000 and higher baud rates.